# How do I know the row number of a location pointer in a 2d array?

Tags: c++

We have a 2d array, and we need to find the row number of the location pointer somewhere in the 2d array.

Comment: please add more context to this question. do u have an example code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: More details please. Do you have an array like arr[r][c] or an array like arr[r * c]. What have you tried?

Comment: please use [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array is declared like:

```
someType array[ROWS][COLS];
```

The row number is

```
(static_cast<char*>(ptr) - static_cast<char*>(array)) / sizeof *array
```

This works because `sizeof *ptr` is the size of a row of the array.

If it's declared as

```
someType array[ROWS * COLS];
```

then it's just

```
(ptr - array) / COLS
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to know is if your array is stored in row-major or column-major order. [From the Wikipedia entry on this subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order):

> The difference is simply that in row-major order, consecutive elements of the rows of the array are contiguous in memory; in column-major order, consecutive elements of the columns are contiguous.

Next you need to know how many items are in a row or column.

Let's assume your array is in row-major order, and each row contains 10 elements. Index 0 through 9 would be on row 1, 10-19 would be on row 2, etc.

With this information, you can calculate the row a given index is on:

```
int row_size = 10;
int index = 45;
int row = index / row_size; // row == 4
```